# How to update Two Columns at the same time with different queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this after insert trigger which updates two different columns based on a join. Basically it turns an Id into a value. This works fine except when one of the Ids does not match (ie, it's zero for the default) Then neither is updated.  If the join fails, it should just insert null.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [AfterHistoryInsert]
ON [Jet].[HistoryEntity]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    Update t1 Set t1.OldValue = t2.Value, t1.NewValue = t3.Value 
        From Jet.HistoryEntity t1
        join Jet.LookupListItemEntity t2 on Cast(t1.OldValue as int) = t2.Id
        join Jet.LookupListItemEntity t3 on Cast(t1.NewValue as int) = t3.Id
        inner join inserted i on i.Id = t1.Id
        where t1.FieldName like '%Id'
END
```

Greg

Comment: Did you try left outer join?

Comment: I have now. Yes, that works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try left outer join instead join

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating into a bigger table, one of the suggestion will be:
-  Selecting all the columns that you want to update(In your case Value) into temp table
- Update Statement by using left outer join to temp table.